# Angular Show a chart when div is visible

Tags: angular, function, show

I have a list of missions, when I click on a mission, through

```
<a (click)="showMission(mission);"...
```

I call this function

```
showMission(mission) {
      this.scrollUp();
      this.mission = mission;
      if (this.showHideMission === false) {
            this.showHideMission = true;
      }

      this.showHideCreateMission = false;
      this.showHideEditMission = false;
  }
```

that change the status of this `div` to `true`

```
<div *ngIf="showHideMission" class="ng-hide m-portlet m-portlet--full-height ">
```

and allow me to read the data inside.

I wanted to show a chart from amchart inside this div, then I inserted

`<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" ></div>`
inside the `<div *ngIf="showHideMission"..`

I created the function that creates the chart

```
createTimelineChart(mission){
let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
...

}
```

And I changed the function `showMission` to :

```
showMission(mission) {
      this.scrollUp();
      this.mission = mission;
      if (this.showHideMission === false) {
            this.showHideMission = true;
      }

      this.showHideCreateMission = false;
      this.showHideEditMission = false;
      this.createTimelineChart(mission); <---ADDED THIS LINE
  }
```

Then, when I open a mission I get this error:

```
html container not found
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: html container not found
    at createChild (Instance.js:129)
    at Module.create (Instance.js:172)
    at MissionComponent.push../src/app/mission/mission.component.ts.MissionComponent.createTimelineChart (mission.component.ts:203)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MissionComponent.ngfactory.js:8278)
    at Object.updateDirectives (core.js:10798)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10692)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10655)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10452)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10692)
```

But if I open a second mission it shows the chart without any error (because the `<div id="chartdiv"..` is already shown), so the real problem here is that it can't finde the div in the first place, although I've called the function to create the chart after setting the `showHideMission` to `true`

Comment: If creation of the chart is synchronous, then you can call the function `this.createTimelineChart(mission)`  before setting the `showHideMission ` variable to true.

Comment: If I call the function before setting `showHideMission` to true I get an error (because it can't find the html container) and I can't even open the mission.. The problem is the html container that seems non visible although I call the function after setting the div to visible

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli try ngstyle or ngclass with attribure hidden/visible instead ngif

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and used arrow functions for the functions. it resolved for me by doing
componentDidUpdate = () => {}

Comment: you can use arrow function in typescript as well

when you pass an arrow function as a callback it remembers who called it / where it is / which context it was called back

so basically my solution was to get a context which is aware of
arrow functions are context aware